# Call string with a variable name

Tags: java, android, string, variables

I'm using android studio and I'm trying to output a particular string via its variable name. Essentially I have a quiz which has a different result depending on the user's answer.

In my java code I have

```
private void displayFinal(String stringVariable) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice);
    String outPut = "some text here \n";
    outPut += stringVariable+"\n";
    outPut += getString(R.string.stringVariable);
    outPut += "\n more text here";
    quantityTextView.setText(outPut);
}
```

Here stringVariable is a string which varies between 1 of 12 values depending on the quiz answers. All 12 of them are defined in my resources.strings file in android studio.

Without the middle portion, the code works fine, but when I try to call a string name via the variable, it doesn't work.

Putting in a specific string name, it works just fine.

Is there any way to put the variable there without some huge nested if/else statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `R.string.stringVariable` obviously will not work since `R.string` is a compiled resource class and `stringVariable` needs to be a dynamic value.

You can use these options instead

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(stringVariable, "string", getPackageName());

textview.setText(resID);  // directly set it
String content = getString(resID); // get the variable, then concatenate with other content
```